# Conda takes 20+ minutes to solve environment when package is already installed

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, virtual-environment

When I type try to run `conda update -n base conda`, conda hung for around 20-minutes on 'Solving environment' and then returned a package plan that did not include an updated version of conda.  The package plan that was returned is provided below.

NOTE: `conda update --all` solved the environment in a reasonable amount of time (~1 min - I didn't time it precisely).

#### Steps to Reproduce

```
conda update -n base conda
```

As I mentioned above, `conda install websocket-client` also hung at 'Solving environment' - I already had websocket-client version 0.53.0 installed when I tried to run the install command

### Expected Behavior

Conda should either:

1. If the most recent version is installed, conda should promptly inform the user that an update isn't needed.
2. If a newer version is available, I'd expect Conda to solve the environment in a shorter period of time. I think that less than 1-2 minutes would be reasonable - 20+ minutes is too long

Originally posted here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7938

Comment: Similar problem. I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 and updating, installing a new package, or changing the python version takes half an hour or more hanging at "Solving environment:".

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Could it be a permissions issue after reinstalling ubuntu?

Comment: I am having the same problem with fbprophet on a Windows 2016 server with full admin privileges. Other packages seem to install OK.

Comment: There's been some activity on the github link that I duplicated. Not really a solution, but some ideas of what might be going on.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### A Common Problem: Suboptimal Channel Prioritization

Anaconda distribution is designed and tested to use the **anaconda** channel (a subset of **defaults**) as its primary channel. Adding **conda-forge** in either a higher- (`channel_priority: strict`) or equal-priority (`channel_priority: flexible`) configuration opens up many of the packages to be sourced from Conda Forge instead, and this is where Conda struggles to solve.

Including **conda-forge** both expands the search as well as opens other packages to be subject to channel switching, and since the `anaconda` package includes dozens of packages, this can be a huge satisfiability problem to solve. This is often most problematic after the first time **conda-forge** is added into a user's configuration.

### Solutions

There are two high-level ways to improve performance: simplify the solving problem or use a faster solver. Of course, these are not mutually exclusive - feel free to be both thoughtful about what you demand of your solver and adopt optimized tools.

#### Option 1: Optimize Channel Prioritization

When the `anaconda` metapackage is installed in an environment, keep the **defaults** channel at highest priority (first channel in `.condarc`) and set `channel_priority: strict`. See [the documentation on Managing Channels](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html#managing-channels).

Additionally, one can forcefully prioritize the **defaults** channel with commands like

```bash
conda update -n base --override-channels -c defaults conda
```

#### Option 2: Mamba

[Mamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a drop-in replacement for the `conda` CLI that is faster (compiled) and in my experience tends to be more aggressive in pruning. Once installed, it runs similar to `conda`, e.g.,

```bash
mamba update -n base conda
```

---

#### Note on Alternative Configuration

Many users find the coupling of their environment management infrastructure (Conda) to a large working environment (Anaconda) to be less than ideal. A popular alternative configuration is to maintain a minimal **base** environment, and if Anaconda is ever needed, to create a new environment with [the `anaconda` *package*](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/anaconda) installed.

Alternative options for **base** environments include

- [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) - minimal **base** with **defaults** channel priority
- [Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge) - minimal **base** with **conda-forge** channel priority
- [Mambaforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge) - Miniforge **base** + Mamba

Comment: Mamba is a relatively fresh player in this game, but it seems to be very promising. I really recommed anyone who is suffering from slow conda transactions to give option 2 a try!

Comment: option 1 works for me. Since I was trying to create a new environment from a requirement files I simply placed **anaconda** before **conda-forge** and it fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Option 1 with the suggested command did not work for me.

Comment: @germ feel free to ping me if you ask a new question with additional details about your situation

Comment: Thank you for this. I just blindly switched from miniconda to mambaforge and an install that took 600+ seconds (terminated after that time) completed in 69.7s.

Answer (score 4):

A better answer for 2023, which is compatible with conda-forge: use the **libmamba** solver.

Conda is actually making this the default going forward, and things should be much faster.

Blog post: https://conda.org/blog/2023-07-05-conda-libmamba-solver-rollout/
Additional info: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/a-faster-conda-for-a-growing-community

To switch to the new solver, first do

```
conda update -n base conda
```

and then

```
conda install -n base conda-libmamba-solver
conda config --set solver libmamba
```

Comment: In my experience, even the most up to date conda is still very slow even with libmamba solver compared to mamba. For me the slowest part is that conda gets stuck on `Collecting package metadata (repodata.json)`, and with mamba for some reason I don't even notice that.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are having problems where the slow down is when it is collecting package metadata (e.g. repodata.json) does the experimental jlap option help?  See the following blog post for more info.

https://conda.org/blog/2023-05-05-how-we-reduced-the-conda-index-fetch-bandwidth/

Answer (score -3):

Upgrade your conda
For particular conda version

```
conda install conda=4.7.12
```

For latest conda version

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

Comment: "conda update -n base -c defaults conda" - isn't this what the OP was trying to do?!