# Poppler installation Anaconda issue

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, poppler

I am trying to install Poppler with Anaconda.

When I run `conda install -c conda-forge poppler` everything freezes
I have tried to run also:

`conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 poppler`

`conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken poppler`

`conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 poppler`

`conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 poppler`

but I get following:

```
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - poppler

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/label/cf201901/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/label/cf201901/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Not sure what I am supposed to do, any ideas welcomed

Comment: `everything freezes` - is it the case for any package or only this one? Just tried the very first install command provided in a clean py3.7 environment - installation seems to be successful (poppler 21.03.0). Never used this package though. So no idea what it is and how it should work.

Comment: Thanks, no it happens only with this didnt have a problem so far.

Comment: This isn't the same question, but the answer is pretty much the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66963979/570918. I doubt anything "*freezes*" - just taking a long time to solve, likely because the environment is large and complicated. Try making environments on a per-project basis, rather than trying to installing every package into a single environment. That will make solving easier and avoid such problems.

Comment: Hi - I ve tried to create new environment on clean py 3.7.6 in jupyter notebooks but again the same. You are right, its not freezing as still page is responsive but not doing anything for hours and hours