# What does it mean if "Collecting package metadata" takes forever?

Tags: anaconda, conda

Should this take longer than 10 minutes to complete?  If not, what might be the problem?  I was able to successfully `conda search` for the package I want, but now it is hanging when I try to install.

Comment: I cover some of it [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66963979/570918).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conda takes 20+ minutes to solve environment when package is already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250933/conda-takes-20-minutes-to-solve-environment-when-package-is-already-installed)

Answer (score 9):

Conda is notoriously slow, as soon as you have more than a handful of packages installed.

The simplest and happiest way forward would probably be to use `mamba` instead of `conda` for installation/updates of new packages and environments.

Mamba has 2.2k stars on Github, works extremely well and is used happily by many many projects. It's probably the solution.

Give it a try and see how it works. Whenever I forget to use `mamba` instead of `conda`, I quickly abort and rerun with `mamba`, because I don't have 10s of minutes to waste.

See here for the docs: https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba

This answer goes into some more depth if Mamba isn't acceptable for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66963979/7483211

Answer (score -1):

I've came with a solution, it may not be the clearest one, but here you have:

```
conda activate <<YOUR_ENV>>
conda install -c anaconda pip
pip install <<PACKAGE>>
```

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the question really