# Difficulty in installing a package in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

There is a package that I wanted to install on Anaconda/Jupyter, called `nutopy`. The documentation about it is given [here](https://ct.gitlabpages.inria.fr/nutopy/).

When I try to install it with Conda using:

```bash
conda install -c control-toolbox -c conda-forge nutopy
```

It keeps solving envirenement forever. Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. There are quite a few posts about this already on here if you search for 'conda solving environment'. You might be able to see the where stalling occurs if your run the command with the `--debug` flag.

Comment: Try starting with a fresh environment. Perhaps your current environment contains packages that conflict with nutopy dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few things, but main issues I see are that the package you want to use is only available for Python 3.7 (except on Linux, which has one 3.9 build) and you are prioritizing **conda-forge** channel in an Anaconda **base**. If you don't already have Python 3.7 in the **base**, Conda is probably wasting a ton of time trying to figure out how to solve this. And over-prioritizing Conda Forge packages in Anaconda **base** is [crushingly difficult to solve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66963979/570918).

General recommendation is to create a new environment, and include the `ipykernel` package if you want to use it as a Jupyter kernel

```bash
conda create -n nutopy -c conda-forge -c control-toolbox python=3.7 nutopy ipykernel
```

You can still launch Jupyter with **base** activated and then change kernels in the notebook.