# Conda's solving environment takes forever

Tags: python, anaconda, package, environment

I am using `conda` since one year, since several weeks, whenever I want to install a package using `conda install -c anaconda <package_name>`, for any package, it is just stuck at the `Solving environment` step.

I just want to install, for example, `sympy` or `mpmath` for Python...

Is there some magic command to solve this problem ?

Thanks and regards

Comment: I'd argue the magic command is `mamba`. You still have to get that installed into **base**, which still may have the initial solving issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66963979/570918

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stuck at Solving Environment on Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63734508/stuck-at-solving-environment-on-anaconda)

Answer (score 15):

**Use `pip` instead of `conda`.**

Nowadays, `Conda` is pretty much broken because its native algorithm does not scale with the number of packages in real-world applications. Its developers are stubborn and reluctant to change and adapt, turning the toolkit more and more useless and hopeless.

FYI, both `pip` and `conda` are Python package managers (developed by different groups of people).

For common Python package installation such as `sympy` and `mpmath`, you can

1. either use Python pip installation:

```
~/anaconda3/bin/python -m pip install sympy mpmath
```

(if your anaconda3 is installed in your home folder, at ~/anaconda3; this command will install Python packages into any folder that your anaconda3 is currently located at (or installed at), e.g., if your anaconda3 is installed at /anaconda3 but moved to /opt/anaconda3, then running `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -m pip install sympy mpmath` will install anaconda3 into /opt/anaconda3; you can run `/opt/anaconda3/pip install sympy mpmath` if your anaconda3 is originally installed at /opt/anaconda3 and not relocated) to install the packages into anaconda3's folder, i.e., ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.*/site-packages/

2. or Linux native installation (e.g. for Ubuntu/Debian-based-Linux):

```
apt-get install python3-sympy python3-mpmath
```

to install the packages into the system folder, i.e., /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/

3. If you use Python conda installation:

```
~/anaconda3/bin/python -m conda install sympy mpmath
```

you often need to wait for hours and might end up with failure or even a corrupted anaconda installation (which I have encountered once in a while and then have to re-install anaconda3 completely).

Some notes to `conda` developers:

- by default, you should not perform a full check on the integrity of all installed packages, just keep an index file listing each package's installation state
- add an option to perform full integrity check on all packages. Since your full integrity check is on per-file level, maybe it can find and solve some conflicts that `pip` cannot do.

Answer (score 8):

A better answer for 2023: keep using conda, but just use the **libmamba** solver.

Conda is actually making this the default going forward, and things should be much faster.

Blog post: https://conda.org/blog/2023-07-05-conda-libmamba-solver-rollout/
Additional info: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/a-faster-conda-for-a-growing-community

To switch to the new solver, first do

```
conda update -n base conda
```

and then

```
conda install -n base conda-libmamba-solver
conda config --set solver libmamba
```

Comment: Oddly, I still had to set the solver on conda 23.9.0  despite their documentation claiming mamba was the default.  Perhaps it's because I upgraded instead of fresh installed.

Comment: @Duane default to `conda-libmamba-solver` starts with 23.10 (see [Release Notes](https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/23.10.0)).

Comment: Tried to install `conda-libmamba-solver`, stuck solving environment again