# Conda stalls on 'retrieving notices:...working...' why?

Tags: python, conda, vpn, virtual-environment

I hadn't used conda for a while (a few months) and when I went to use it the other day, any conda install call resulted in it returning the message 'retrieving notices:...working..' and then nothing, even when left for a long time. For context, I am working on windows 10, and have a VPN for work that cannot be turned off if access to the internet is needed. Conda has worked with this VPN before, and I'm not aware of any changes to the VPN at present. The problem persists whether I am using the conda or conda-forge channels.

I reinstalled my anaconda, but the problem persists. I've looked for other examples of this, but I can't find any reports of conda stalling for others at this point. Given the lack of output, I'm not even sure how to query this further. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: The libmamba solver might be worth a try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77090765/765091

Comment: Hi did you figure out a solution? I'm facing the same issue but on Mac.