# Conda Config channels caused warning

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda, conda

I configured my conda channels by adding the channels conda-forge and anaconda but now receive this warning whenever I run any conda command in terminal no matter what environment I am in:

```
C:\Users\henry\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py:102: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.8) or chardet (5.1.0)/charset_normalizer (2.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({})/charset_normalizer ({}) doesn't match a supported "
C:\Users\henry\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda_package_streaming\package_streaming.py:19: UserWarning: zstandard could not be imported. Running without .conda support.
  warnings.warn("zstandard could not be imported. Running without .conda support.")
C:\Users\henry\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py:29: UserWarning: Install zstandard Python bindings for .conda support
  _warnings.warn("Install zstandard Python bindings for .conda support")
```

---

I tried updating all of my conda libraries by running conda update all but it just buffered for literally twelve hours before I stopped it. I also cleaned the cache but that did nothing.

Comment: Anaconda **base** is pretty much incompatible with `conda-forge` being the prioritized channel. Users that want to use Conda Forge are often better off with a minimal **base** environment. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250933/conda-takes-20-minutes-to-solve-environment-when-package-is-already-installed/66963979#66963979

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the issue is that zstandard is not installed

First, double check to see if zstandard is installed:

Run this in your Anaconda prompt/Terminal:

```
conda list zstandard
```

If it's not installed, use this command to install zstandard using conda forge:

```
conda install -c conda-forge zstandard
```

On the other hand, if it is installed, then, there could be an issue with your zstandard package. Try this:

```
conda update zstandard
```

If that still doesn't work, it could be that you might have conflicting packages in your environment. So, create a new environment and then, install zstandard.

Should resolve your issue.

Comment: Why `conda-forge` channel? I wouldn't recommend *Anaconda* users to install Conda Forge packages in **base**. They should strictly use the `defaults` (`anaconda`) channel when working with their **base** environment. Otherwise, they end up with [situations like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53250933/conda-takes-20-minutes-to-solve-environment-when-package-is-already-installed/66963979#66963979).

Comment: @merv, I'm assuming OP meant it in their specifically set-up Anaconda environment. Not in base

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is listed when I run conda list zstandard, but when I try to update it, I get stuck in a buffer loop of solving the enviroment forever (at least 12 hours).  Making a new environment did not seem to help.

Comment: Embarrassingly, it seems I somehow overlooked the fact that OP explicitly added `conda-forge` as a channel. Sorry if I was ascribing that to you. That would be the root cause - and your recommendation is right, except that this is about **base** and what I said applies (Anaconda **base** + Conda Forge prioritized = infinite solving).

Comment: @HenryCarlson, would you be cool with removing conda-forge? If so, use this: `conda config --remove channels conda-forge`. As @merv mentioned, this could be the root cause for the warning